# Purpose of VERSIONNAME in sfdx force:package:version:create

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

In the [SFDX CLI Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm), the commands `force:package:version:create` takes both a `VERSIONNUMBER` & `VERSIONNAME`.

The description for `VERSIONNAME` is:

> -a | --versionname VERSIONNAME Optional The name of the package version to be created. Overrides the sfdx-project.json value.

However, I'm wondering where this is actually used?

In other words, where one actually see whatever value I set here and what (if any) impact does it make?

Comment: looks like one place it shows up is when opening the "packaging/installPackage" page (along side the number).  Still no clue why both are needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a descriptive name that serves as an alternative label for administrators to identify which version they have. For example, you might have a package version 4.2.1.4, but it might be called "Summer 2019 Hotfix 2". The former is useful for Apex code/etc to determine the installed version, but the latter is generally more useful for humans.

It shows up in places where you can list packages. I believe that only applies to the CLI for now, but it may also appear in the user interface at a later time, the same way it does for managed packages today. It has absolutely zero impact if you use it or not, but you may find it useful to at least identify major releases with a descriptive label.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks